# Bad enforcement of clippy rule?

Tags: rust, shadowing, rust-clippy

I have disallowed unrelated shadowing in variable declarations.

But now this rule gives me an error on these two lines

```rust
let overflow: bool;
(self.standing, overflow) = self.standing.overflowing_add(reason.to_severity());
```

The linting error I get is:

```
error: `overflow` shadows a previous, unrelated binding
  --> src/models/peer.rs:73:25
   |
73 |         (self.standing, overflow) = self.standing.overflowing_add(reason.to_severity());
   |                         ^^^^^^^^
   |
note: the lint level is defined here
  --> src/lib.rs:1:9
   |
1  | #![deny(clippy::shadow_unrelated)]
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: previous binding is here
  --> src/models/peer.rs:73:10
   |
73 |         (self.standing, overflow) = self.standing.overflowing_add(reason.to_severity());
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#shadow_unrelated
```

I'm using version `1.62.0` of the rust compiler.

My thoughts are that this behavior is a bug. The above lines should be allowed under this clippy rule. Am I wrong?

The problem can be seen [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=e1b7b534644d137b6b72d767848fd6f5). Thanks to @Jmp for writing this illustration of the problem.

Comment: Can we have a MWE?

Comment: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=e1b7b534644d137b6b72d767848fd6f5)

Comment: The above example from @Jmb shows the problem. The error shows up if you press `TOOLS` -> `Clippy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reported bug - [rust-clippy#6141](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/6141#issuecomment-758330154).

I think the problem is that the destructuring assignment is desugared into a `let` declaration that reuses the same span, and this causes clippy to think it has the same name and thus shadowing.

Comment: This 'reported bug' is from the beginning of 2021 ... Was it fixed? Will it be fixed?